# How to query from different app insights in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I have different application insights within different directories and then different subscriptions.

> WebAPI1: ApplInsights1, Subscription1, Directory1
>
> WebAPI2:ApplInsights2, Subscription2, Directory2

I want to get the percentage of HTTP requests of endpoints for both APIs. sp for example If there are 100 requests for API1 and 100 for API2 and there is one endpoint which is called 10 times. then the percentage will be 5.

I am able to get the individual API, But I am not able to get the combined result in one single query window. Please help. I am very new to KQL.

Below is the query for WebAPI1.

```
requests
| where cloud_RoleName == "WebAPI1"
| summarize count() by operation_Name
| extend percentage = 100.0 * count_ / toscalar(requests | where cloud_RoleName == "WebAPI1"| count)
| project operation_Name, percentage
| order by percentage desc
```

**Note**: I am new to KQL so please ignore silly mistakes in my question.

Edit: I have tried what has been told by Rithwik, But I can't see an option to select subscriptions. It shows only one subscription.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to query from different app insights in Azure?

Yes, you can query, Firstly open Monitor in Azure Portal Then set scope(according to your requirements) like below:

[image]

For requests logs of App services logs and Function app logs you can use below :

```
AppRequests 
|where AppRoleName contains "x" or AppRoleName contains "y"
```

[image]

This is one of way of doing, Other way is to export logs to  a Log analytics workspace and then also you can query the results from that workspace.

Comment: It's showing only one subscription. Please check my updated answer. Also, I want to query across directories as well.

Comment: Try to follow this https://i.imgur.com/GOS3ZV4.png

Comment: It's not showing me Subscription dropdown

Comment: It looks like the other subscriptions is not under same directory as your current subscription, In order to associate other subscriptions to same directory follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory#associate-a-subscription-to-a-directory)

Comment: If the subscription dropdown is greyed out, then user does not have required permissions to read the other subscription. Make sure you have atleast contributor role assigned at all subscriptions level

Comment: I can't do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254036/discussion-between-rithwikbojja-and-vivek-nuna).